# Pear package not resolved

Tags: php, pear, composer-php

All of a sudden composer fails to resolve a particular pear package (net_gearman). Previously everything worked without any problems. On my developer machine I don't get any errors and the package installs succesfully, but on the CI server I keep getting the following error:

```
     [exec] Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
     [exec] Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
     [exec] 
     [exec]   Problem 1
     [exec]     - acsi/acsi-job dev-trunk requires pear-pear/net_gearman * -> no     matching package found.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Potential causes:
     [exec]  - A typo in the package name
     [exec]  - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your    minimum-stability setting
     [exec]    see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.
     [exec] 
     [exec] Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

My root composer.json defines the pear repository:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "pear",
            "url": "http://pear.php.net"
        }
    ]
}
```

Another package requires the Net_Gearman library:

```
{
    "require": {
        "pear-pear/Net_Gearman": "*",
        "pear-pear/PEAR": "*"
    }
}
```

I am running the composer command after a clean VCS checkout, so don't have a vendor map and composer.lock yet. I have tried with the following commands:

```
composer install --prefer-dist
composer install --prefer-source
```

Both resulting in the same error as mentioned above.
Anyone have a suggestion how I could resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
{
    "require": {
        "pear-pear.php.net/Net_Gearman": "*",
    }
}
```